# how to access python object in javascript function?

Tags: javascript, python, cherrypy, genshi

that means now i am working on python with cherryypy and genshi framework with help of this i send python variable to html file using genshi but i want to access variable that variable in javascript function so how can i do?..

html file is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
      xmlns:py="http://genshi.edgewall.org/">
<head>
    <title>Home</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function setparent(val) {
            document.getElementById("tpar").value=val;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div >
        <table>
            <div py:for="user in users">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div title="${user.userid}" onclick="setparent('${user.userid}')">${user.fname+" "+ user.lname}</div>
                        <py:if test="user.resource.__len__() > 0">
                            <div>
                                <py:for each="res in user.resource">
                                    <div><a href="">${user.resource[res]}</a></div>
                                </py:for>
                            </div>
                        </py:if>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </div>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

as  i want to access "users" variable of py into javascriptfunction

can u tell me this?

Comment: Please take all the unnecessary code out of your example and show only what is important. Right now it is very difficult to read.

Comment: Your <table> contains a <div> that is not in a <tr> - this is bad syntax. `<div py:for="user in users">` should probably be replaced with `<py:for each="user in users">`.

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to pass values from python to javascript is - especially if they can contain more than just plain numbers or a very restricted charset (basically `[a-zA-Z0-9]` and non-quoting symbols) - running the value through a json encoder (`json.dumps(...)`) to ensure they do not break anything.

Comment: ok thanks sir.... but i want to pass object of some class to jacascript.. is it possible in python?

Comment: You just have to ensure it can be serialized into a json object. See the documentation of your json module for details.